# Auto save Facebook page post into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I'm trying to do here is make a script that checks a Facebook page for a new post, and if there is a new post, I want this script to insert the post into the database.

For example,

I upload a photo with a caption on my Facebook page.
Then, the script inserts these credentials into the database with the values ID, Post and Photo URL.

I am pretty experienced with PHP but not so much with the Facebook API.

How would I do this?

Comment: If it is your page use real time updates. Facebook will ping you every time a new post is made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an RSS feed of your page:
see this link https://www.facebook.com/help/212445198787494

just parse the xml and do `insert unique` query after indexing pubDate as unique

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know why I didn't think of that!